# UIPickerView Chaging frame Size and positon

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Are there any way I can change the size of the PickerView and its position at runtime. What I do need to do was when A certain Row in A certain Component is selected I will got to show the another pickerView on the right side then the first PickerView will resize itself and change its position so that the new PickerView will be seen.

I don't want to put the value of the second PickerView on the First PickerView cause some items in the first PickerView doesn't have any relation or doesn't need to show other values.

Answer (score 0):

The height and width of picker views is hardwired and unchangeable. (I suspect because of the requirements of the quasi-3D rotation animation.)

The picker view will fill the screen right to left. The only thing you can do is move them up and down.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the design file using a text editor, then find the portion related to the picker view,  and finally change the width-height of the pickerview. However, please keep in mind that this also has some limit.